# Help with using the Runge-Kutta 4th order method on a system of 2 first order ODE's.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, runge-kutta-methods

The original ODE I had was $$ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\frac{dy}{dx}-6y=0$$ with $y(0)=3$ and $y'(0)=1$. Now I can solve this by hand and obtain that $y(1) = 14.82789927$. However I wish to use the 4th order Runge-Kutta method, so I have the system:

$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
  \frac{dy}{dx} = z \\
  \frac{dz}{dx} = 6y - z
\end{array}\right.
$$
With $y(0)=3$ and $z(0)=1$.

Now I know that for two general 1st order ODE's $$ \frac{dy}{dx} = f(x,y,z) \\ \frac{dz}{dx}=g(x,y,z)$$ The 4th order Runge-Kutta formula's for a system of 2 ODE's are: $$ y_{i+1}=y_i + \frac{1}{6}(k_0+2k_1+2k_2+k_3) \\ z_{i+1}=z_i + \frac{1}{6}(l_0+2l_1+2l_2+l_3) $$ Where $$k_0 = hf(x_i,y_i,z_i) \\ k_1 = hf(x_i+\frac{1}{2}h,y_i+\frac{1}{2}k_0,z_i+\frac{1}{2}l_0) \\ k_2 = hf(x_i+\frac{1}{2}h,y_i+\frac{1}{2}k_1,z_i+\frac{1}{2}l_1) \\ k_3 = hf(x_i+h,y_i+k_2,z_i+l_2) $$ and $$l_0 = hg(x_i,y_i,z_i) \\ l_1 = hg(x_i+\frac{1}{2}h,y_i+\frac{1}{2}k_0,z_i+\frac{1}{2}l_0) \\ l_2 = hg(x_i+\frac{1}{2}h,y_i+\frac{1}{2}k_1,z_i+\frac{1}{2}l_1) \\ l_3 = hg(x_i+h,y_i+k_2,z_i+l_2)$$

My problem is I am struggling to apply this method to my system of ODE's so that I can program a method that can solve any system of 2 first order ODE's using the formulas above, I would like for someone to please run through one step of the method, so I can understand it better.

Comment: For reference, see [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10147822/380384).

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I will outline the process and you can fill in the calculations.

We have our system as:

$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
  \frac{dy}{dx} = z \\
  \frac{dz}{dx} = 6y - z
\end{array}\right.
$$
With $y(0)=3$ and $z(0)=1$.

We must do the calculations in a certain order as there are dependencies between the numerical calculations. This order is:

- $k_0 = hf(x_i,y_i,z_i)$
- $l_0 = hg(x_i,y_i,z_i)$
- $k_1 = hf(x_i+\frac{1}{2}h,y_i+\frac{1}{2}k_0,z_i+\frac{1}{2}l_0)$
- $l_1 = hg(x_i+\frac{1}{2}h,y_i+\frac{1}{2}k_0,z_i+\frac{1}{2}l_0)$
- $k_2 = hf(x_i+\frac{1}{2}h,y_i+\frac{1}{2}k_1,z_i+\frac{1}{2}l_1)$
- $l_2 = hg(x_i+\frac{1}{2}h,y_i+\frac{1}{2}k_1,z_i+\frac{1}{2}l_1)$
- $k_3 = hf(x_i+h,y_i+k_2,z_i+l_2)$
- $l_3 = hg(x_i+h,y_i+k_2,z_i+l_2)$
- $y_{i+1}=y_i + \frac{1}{6}(k_0+2k_1+2k_2+k_3)$
- $z_{i+1}=z_i + \frac{1}{6}(l_0+2l_1+2l_2+l_3)$

We typically need some inputs for the algorithm:

- A range that we want to do the calculations over: $a \le t \le b$, lets use $a = 0, b = 1$.
- The number of steps $N$, say $N = 10$.
- The steps size $h = \dfrac{b-a}{N} = \dfrac{1}{10}$

The system we are solving is:

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = f(x,y,z) = z \\ \frac{dz}{dx}=g(x,y,z) = 6y - z$$

Doing the calculations using the above order for the first time step $i= 0, t_0 = 0 = x_0$, yields:

- $k_0 = hf(x_0,y_0,z_0) = \dfrac{1}{10}(z_0) = \dfrac{1}{10}(1) = \dfrac{1}{10}$
- $l_0 = hg(x_0,y_0,z_0) = \dfrac{1}{10}(6y_0 - z_0) = \dfrac{1}{10}(6 \times 3 - 1) = \dfrac{1}{10}(17)$
- $k_1 = hf(x_0+\frac{1}{2}h,y_0+\frac{1}{2}k_0,z_0+\frac{1}{2}l_0) = \dfrac{1}{10}(1 + \dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{1}{10}(17)) ~~$(You please continue the calcs.)
- $l_1 = hg(x_0+\frac{1}{2}h,y_i+\frac{1}{2}k_0,z_0+\frac{1}{2}l_0)$
- $k_2 = hf(x_0+\frac{1}{2}h,y_0+\frac{1}{2}k_1,z_0+\frac{1}{2}l_1)$
- $l_2 = hg(x_0+\frac{1}{2}h,y_0+\frac{1}{2}k_1,z_0+\frac{1}{2}l_1)$
- $k_3 = hf(x_0+h,y_0+k_2,z_0+l_2)$
- $l_3 = hg(x_0+h,y_0+k_2,z_0+l_2)$
- $y_{1}=y_0 + \frac{1}{6}(k_0+2k_1+2k_2+k_3)$
- $z_{1}=z_0 + \frac{1}{6}(l_0+2l_1+2l_2+l_3)$

You now have $x_1$ and $z_1$ which you need for the next time step after all of the intermediate (in order again). Now, we move on to the next time step $i = 1, t_1 = t_0 + h = \dfrac{1}{10} = x_1$, so we have:

- $k_0 = hf(x_1,y_1,z_1) = \dfrac{1}{10}(z_1)$
- $l_0 = hg(x_1,y_1,z_1) = \dfrac{1}{10}(6y_1 - z_1)$
- $k_1 = hf(x_1+\frac{1}{2}h,y_1+\frac{1}{2}k_0,z_1+\frac{1}{2}l_0)$
- $l_1 = hg(x_1+\frac{1}{2}h,y_1+\frac{1}{2}k_0,z_1+\frac{1}{2}l_0)$
- $k_2 = hf(x_1+\frac{1}{2}h,y_1+\frac{1}{2}k_1,z_1+\frac{1}{2}l_1)$
- $l_2 = hg(x_1+\frac{1}{2}h,y_1+\frac{1}{2}k_1,z_1+\frac{1}{2}l_1)$
- $k_3 = hf(x_1+h,y_1+k_2,z_1+l_2)$
- $l_3 = hg(x_1+h,y_1+k_2,z_1+l_2)$
- $y_{2}=y_1 + \frac{1}{6}(k_0+2k_1+2k_2+k_3)$
- $z_{2}=z_1 + \frac{1}{6}(l_0+2l_1+2l_2+l_3)$

Continue this for $10$ time steps. Your final result should match closely (assuming the numerical algorithm is stable for this problem) to the exact solution. You will compare $z_{10}$ to the exact result. The exact solution is:

$$y(x) = e^{-3 x}+2 e^{2 x}$$

If we find $y(1) = \dfrac{1}{e^3} + 2 e^2 = 14.8278992662291643974401973...$.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough response, seeing the start of it I now understand it better. Thanks!

Comment: Also, shouldn't I be comparing $y_{10}$ with the exact result? Because $z_{10}$ would be used for $y'(1)$, right?

Comment: Recall, in your new system, the first equation $y' = z$ is just a dummy variable in order to use RK4 methods. Regards

Comment: @Michael: Also, you will clearly see when you calculate $y_i, z_i$, which is the correct final result.

Comment: Late reply but, is $y_i$ or $z_i$ the solution to the original ODE? Comparing values it seems like the solution is given by $y_i$, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @ErikVesterlund for me as well, the solution is being by yi.

Comment: @ErikVesterlund if I got this right, then z would be the solution for the derivative of y and y is the solution to the original ODE

Answer (score 21):

Although this answer contains the same content as Amzoti's answer, I think it's worthwhile to see it another way.

In general consider if you had $m$ first-order ODE's (after appropriate decomposition). The system looks like

\begin{align*}
\frac{d y_1}{d x} &= f_1(x, y_1, \ldots, y_m) \\
\frac{d y_2}{d x} &= f_2(x, y_1, \ldots, y_m) \\
&\,\,\,\vdots\\
\frac{d y_m}{d x} &= f_m(x, y_1, \ldots, y_m) \\
\end{align*}

Define the vectors $\vec{Y} = (y_1, \ldots, y_m)$ and $\vec{f} = (f_1, \ldots, f_m)$, then we can write the system as

$$\frac{d}{dx} \vec{Y} = \vec{f}(x,\vec{Y})$$

Now we can generalize the RK method by defining 
\begin{align*}
\vec{k}_1 &= h\vec{f}\left(x_n,\vec{Y}(x_n)\right)\\
\vec{k}_2 &= h\vec{f}\left(x_n + \tfrac{1}{2}h,\vec{Y}(x_n) + \tfrac{1}{2}\vec{k}_1\right)\\
\vec{k}_3 &= h\vec{f}\left(x_n + \tfrac{1}{2}h,\vec{Y}(x_n) + \tfrac{1}{2}\vec{k}_2\right)\\
\vec{k}_4 &= h\vec{f}\left(x_n + h, \vec{Y}(x_n) + \vec{k}_3\right)
\end{align*}

and the solutions are then given by
$$\vec{Y}(x_{n+1}) = \vec{Y}(x_n) + \tfrac{1}{6}\left(\vec{k}_1 + 2\vec{k}_2 + 2\vec{k}_3 + \vec{k}_4\right)$$

with $m$ initial conditions specified by $\vec{Y}(x_0)$. When writing a code to implement this one can simply use arrays, and write a function to compute $\vec{f}(x,\vec{Y})$

For the example provided, we have $\vec{Y} = (y,z)$ and $\vec{f} = (z, 6y-z)$. Here's an example in Fortran90:

```
program RK4
    implicit none   
    integer , parameter :: dp = kind(0.d0)
    integer , parameter :: m = 2 ! order of ODE
    real(dp) :: Y(m)
    real(dp) :: a, b, x, h
    integer :: N, i 

    ! Number of steps
    N = 10

    ! initial x
    a = 0
    x = a

    ! final x
    b = 1

    ! step size
    h = (b-a)/N

    ! initial conditions
    Y(1) = 3 ! y(0)
    Y(2) = 1 ! y'(0)

    ! iterate N times
    do i = 1,N
        Y = iterate(x, Y)
        x = x + h
    end do

    print*, Y


contains

    ! function f computes the vector f

    function f(x, Yvec) result (fvec)
        real(dp) :: x
        real(dp) :: Yvec(m), fvec(m)

        fvec(1) = Yvec(2) !z
        fvec(2) = 6*Yvec(1) - Yvec(2) !6y-z

    end function

    ! function iterate computes Y(t_n+1)

    function iterate(x, Y_n) result (Y_nplus1)
        real(dp) :: x
        real(dp) :: Y_n(m), Y_nplus1(m)
        real(dp) :: k1(m), k2(m), k3(m), k4(m)

        k1 = h*f(x, Y_n)
        k2 = h*f(x + h/2, Y_n + k1/2)
        k3 = h*f(x + h/2, Y_n + k2/2)
        k4 = h*f(x + h, Y_n + k3)

        Y_nplus1 = Y_n + (k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4)/6

    end function

end program
```

This can be applied to any set of $m$ first order ODE's, just change `m` in the code and change the function `f` to whatever is appropriate for the system of interest. Running this code as-is yields

$   14.827578509968953    \qquad    29.406156886687729$

The first value is $y(1)$, the second $z(1)$, correct to the third decimal point with only ten steps.

Comment: you should use $x_{n}$ instead of $t_{n}$

Comment: Good catch, fixed it

Comment: Fantastic answer @Kai +1. Would give +50 if possible! Many people struggle with systems of ODE's and RK methods. I have a question though regarding your Fortran implementation. If you wanted to be fancy you could write your $k_i$'s using a for loop correct? Essentially placing them in an array? So you would have an array $k(i,n)$ where i was the number of stages and n was the dimension of your state vector? Are you aware of any documentation that does this in Fortran? I am writing something similar at the minute and am a bit stumped!!

Comment: I have noticed that there is no explicit dependence of function `f` on variable `x`. Is that because of the substitution we used to reduce the order of derivative? Will this dependence on `x` be automatically picked up by the algorithm through other variables?

Comment: @MadPhysicist the ODE in the original question didn't have explicit $x$ dependence, it's only implicit in $y(x)$ and $z(x)$. You could have explicit $x$ dependence of course

Answer (score 8):

A Matlab implementation is given below:

```
% It calculates ODE using Runge-Kutta 4th order method
% Author Ido Schwartz
% Originally available form: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29851-runge-kutta-4th-order-ode/content/Runge_Kutta_4.m
% Edited by Amin A. Mohammed, for 2 ODEs(April 2016)

clc;                                               % Clears the screen
clear all;

h=0.1;                                             % step size
x = 0:h:1;                                         % Calculates upto y(1)
y = zeros(1,length(x)); 
z = zeros(1,length(x)); 
y(1) = 3;                                          % initial condition
z(1) = 1;                                          % initial condition
% F_xy = @(t,r) 3.*exp(-t)-0.4*r;                  % change the function as you desire
F_xyz = @(x,y,z) z;                                  % change the function as you desire
G_xyz = @(x,y,z) 6*y-z;

for i=1:(length(x)-1)                              % calculation loop
    k_1 = F_xyz(x(i),y(i),z(i));
    L_1 = G_xyz(x(i),y(i),z(i));
    k_2 = F_xyz(x(i)+0.5*h,y(i)+0.5*h*k_1,z(i)+0.5*h*L_1);
    L_2 = G_xyz(x(i)+0.5*h,y(i)+0.5*h*k_1,z(i)+0.5*h*L_1);
    k_3 = F_xyz((x(i)+0.5*h),(y(i)+0.5*h*k_2),(z(i)+0.5*h*L_2));
    L_3 = G_xyz((x(i)+0.5*h),(y(i)+0.5*h*k_2),(z(i)+0.5*h*L_2));
    k_4 = F_xyz((x(i)+h),(y(i)+k_3*h),(z(i)+L_3*h)); % Corrected        
    L_4 = G_xyz((x(i)+h),(y(i)+k_3*h),(z(i)+L_3*h));

    y(i+1) = y(i) + (1/6)*(k_1+2*k_2+2*k_3+k_4)*h;  % main equation
    z(i+1) = z(i) + (1/6)*(L_1+2*L_2+2*L_3+L_4)*h;  % main equation

end
```

Answer (score 0):

A [Fortran code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xICDW.png) shown below:

[image]

produces the following [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2Qlf.png)

[image: output]

```
!Runge-Kutta Fourth Order Method

!For 2nd Order Differentiation Equation

!First you have to define the function

F(x,y,z) = z !dy/dx

G(x,y,z) = 6*y-z !dz/dx = d2y/dx2

INTEGER :: n,i

REAL :: k1,l1,k2,l2,k3,l3,k4,l4    !Most Important

Write (*,*) "Given Equation '(y2)-6(y1)+(y0)=0'"

Write (*,*) "Xo=0, Yo=3, Zo=Y'o=1, Xn=1, n=?"

Xo=0    !Given Condition

Yo=3    !Given Condition

Zo=1    !Given Condition

Xn=1    !Given Condition

read (*,*) n    !n=number of Intercept

h=(Xn-Xo)/n

do i=1,n    !you have to do the Calculation 'n' times

k1 = h*F(Xo,Yo,Zo)

l1 = h*G(Xo,Yo,Zo)

k2 = h*F(Xo+h/2,Yo+k1/2,Zo+l1/2)

l2 = h*G(Xo+h/2,Yo+k1/2,Zo+l1/2)

k3 = h*F(Xo+h/2,Yo+k2/2,Zo+l2/2)

l3 = h*G(Xo+h/2,Yo+k2/2,Zo+l2/2)

k4 = h*F(Xo+h,Yo+k3,Zo+l3)

l4 = h*G(Xo+h,Yo+k3,Zo+l3)

!Sum Up

Yn = Yo+(k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)/6

Zn = Zo+(l1+2*l2+2*l3+l4)/6

!Operation for Next calculation

Xo=Xo+h     !(+h) than previous Term

Yo=Yn    !Now Yn becomes Yo

Zo=Zn    !Now Zn becomes Zo

End Do

Write (*,*) "Xn,Yn =",Xo,Yo

Stop

End
```

Comment: Can your clarify your question?

Answer (score 0):

A Rust implementation is below:

```
const M: usize = 2; // Size of the system

fn main() {
    let mut y: [f64; M] = [0.0; M];
    let mut a: f64 = 0.0;
    let mut x: f64 = a;
    let mut b: f64 = 0.0;
    let n: usize = 10;
    let h: f64 = (b - a) / n as f64;

    // Initial conditions
    y[0] = 3.0; // y(0)
    y[1] = 1.0; // y'(0)

    for _i in 0..n {
        y = rk4_step(x, y, h, &derivatives);
        x += h;
    }

    println!("{:?}", y);
}

// Define the derivatives for the system of equations
fn derivatives(x: f64, y: [f64; M]) -> [f64; M] {
    let mut dy_dx: [f64; M] = [0.0; M];

    dy_dx[0] = y[1]; // dy/dx = z
    dy_dx[1] = 6.0 * y[0] - y[1]; // dz/dx = 6y - z

    dy_dx
}

// Perform one step of RK4
fn rk4_step(x: f64, y_n: [f64; M], h: f64, f: &dyn Fn(f64, [f64; M]) -> [f64; M]) -> [f64; M] {
    let mut k1: [f64; M] = [0.0; M];
    let mut k2: [f64; M] = [0.0; M];
    let mut k3: [f64; M] = [0.0; M];
    let mut k4: [f64; M] = [0.0; M];
    let mut y_n_plus_1: [f64; M] = [0.0; M];

    k1 = scale_vec(&f(x, y_n), h);
    k2 = scale_vec(&f(x + h / 2.0, add_vec(&y_n, &scale_vec(&k1, 0.5))), h);
    k3 = scale_vec(&f(x + h / 2.0, add_vec(&y_n, &scale_vec(&k2, 0.5))), h);
    k4 = scale_vec(&f(x + h, add_vec(&y_n, &k3)), h);

    y_n_plus_1 = add_vec(
        &y_n,
        &scale_vec(
            &add_vec(&k1, &add_vec(&scale_vec(&k2, 2.0), &add_vec(&scale_vec(&k3, 2.0), &k4))),
            1.0 / 6.0,
        ),
    );

    y_n_plus_1
}

// Helper function: element-wise vector addition
fn add_vec(a: &[f64; M], b: &[f64; M]) -> [f64; M] {
    let mut result: [f64; M] = [0.0; M];
    for i in 0..M {
        result[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    }
    result
}

// Helper function: element-wise scalar multiplication of a vector
fn scale_vec(a: &[f64; M], scalar: f64) -> [f64; M] {
    let mut result: [f64; M] = [0.0; M];
    for i in 0..M {
        result[i] = a[i] * scalar;
    }
    result
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).