# Reduce this third order ordinary differential equation to first order to use Runge Kutta

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

The ODE I'm working with is
$$\dddot{x} + t^2\ddot{x} + 4x = 0$$ with $$x(0)=1, \dot{x}(0)=0, \ddot{x}=-1$$

I've written a very basic program in C++ to use the RK4 method to approximate a solution to first order ODEs. To get this particular ODE to be compatible with my code, I imagine I have to reduce the order to make this into a first order equation.

However, I don't really know how to go about this as generally I have only encountered this reduction issue with second order ODEs.

Can anyone help me get started or point me to somewhere with a thorough explanation/examples? I must admit my knowledge of ODEs is a bit rusty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your suspicions are correct, you can convert an $n-th$ order differential equation  into an n-dimensional system of [*first order equations*](http://www.math.poly.edu/courses/ma2132/Notes/MA2132EquationsToSystems.pdf).

Let $x_1 = x$, and then we have:

$$\begin{align} x_1' &= x' = x_2 \\ x_2' &= x'' = x_3 \\ x_3' &= x''' =  -t^2 x_3 - 4 x_1 \end{align}$$

Our new system is:

$$\begin{align} x_1' &= x_2 \\ x_2' &= x_3 \\ x_3' &= -t^2 x_3 - 4 x_1 \end{align}$$

We are now left with converting the initial conditions, and we get:

$$x_1(0) = 1, x_2(0) = 0, x_3(0) = -1$$

Here are more [*examples-1*](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/SystemsDE.aspx) and [*examples-2*](https://www.math.ohiou.edu/courses/math3600/lecture29.pdf).

Now you can apply the Runge-Kutta method to this first-order system of equations. You can see an example in [Help with using the Runge-Kutta 4th order method on a system of 2 first order ODE's.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/721076/help-with-using-the-runge-kutta-4th-order-method-on-a-system-of-2-first-order-od). Of course, you have to modify this for the third equation.

Here are some [*worked examples*](https://math.berkeley.edu/~zworski/128/psol12.pdf) including numerical results.

Comment: You can also look at the link example and now search out more such examples.

Comment: I'm having difficulty following this, but thanks for taking the time to respond.
Should I be trying to split up $$x'_3+t^2x_3+4x_1=0$$into two or more equations? Or am I to use the same technique as in the answer you linked, except with 3 different Runge Kutta equations at the same time as opposed to the 2 in your other example?

Comment: You will go from a single third-order equation to a system of three first order systems. You now have to account for solving a system using Runge-Kutta. Clear? When solving a system, you would use something like: https://www.nsc.liu.se/~boein/f77to90/rk.html

Comment: I think I'm starting to get a clearer picture in my head. I see that you've taken the single third-order equation and by substitution given three first order systems. 
The example in your most recent link; just to be clear, I'll need an extra line in each stage of the RK equations, to account for the extra equation in my system, correct?

Comment: Yes, correct, I added a link for some worked numerical examples. They do the conversion as above and then show numerical results. Keep working it until you get the aha moment!

Comment: I'll mark the question as answered, since you've done a pretty thorough job of that, thanks. I might encounter follow-up queries though which I may post as comments. Thanks again.

Comment: @user142340: You might like to peruse the C++ code at: http://sherrytowers.com/2014/10/15/a-c-class-for-numerically-solving-odes/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20620/discussion-between-user142340-and-amzoti).