# Solve fourth order ODE using fourth order Runge-Kutta method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

I have been trying to solve some ODEs in C language using RK4 method. So far I have been able to solve first and second order ODEs by using direct formulae as follows:

**First order ODE:**

> $$x_{n+1} = x_n + h\\
> y_{n+1} = y_n + \frac{1}{6}(k_1 + 2k_2 + 2k_3 + k_4) 
> $$
>   where $$
> k_1 = h f(x_n, y_n)\\ 
> k_2 = h f(x_n + h/2, y_n + k_1/2)\\
> k_3 = h f(x_n + h/2, y_n + k_2/2)\\
> k_4 = h f(x_n + h, y_n + k_3)
> $$

**Second Order ODE**

[image]

However I am unable to find any direct formulae to solve higher order ODEs(3rd and 4th order). Is there a straight forward way to implement RK4 for higher order ODEs?

Comment: @Moo I understand that but it would be helpful for me to understand the solving through an example and also to verify the result once I am done coding the same. I am unable to find any resource which would help me with theis

Comment: Consider the ODEs in this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1120984/reduce-this-third-order-ordinary-differential-equation-to-first-order-to-use-run

How will I write the corresponding equations for k1,...k4 for the above?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41996542/error-when-solving-ordinary-differential-equation-numerically-in-c-error-expe for a discussion of the algorithm from the book "Numerical recipes in C". Starting with dimensions 3-4 it makes sense to treat vectors as vectors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, higher-order ODEs are rewritten as a system of first-order ODEs. To illustrate this, an example is provided below.

Let us consider the ODE $x^{(4)} + x^{(3)} + x'' + x' + x = y(t)$, with $x(t_0) = x_0$, $x'(t_0) = \dot x_0$, $x''(t_0) = \ddot x_0$, $x^{(3)}(t_0) = \dddot x_0$. Using the vector notation $\boldsymbol{x} = (x,x',x'',x^{(3)})^\top = (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)^\top$, the ODE is rewritten
$$
\underbrace{
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x'_1 \\
x'_2 \\
x'_3 \\
x'_4
\end{array}
\right)}_{\boldsymbol{x}'}
=
\underbrace{
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x_2 \\
x_3 \\
x_4 \\
y(t) - x_4 - x_3 - x_2 - x_1
\end{array}
\right)}_{\boldsymbol{f}(\boldsymbol{x},t)} ,
$$
with the initial condition $\boldsymbol{x}(t_0) = (x_0,\dot x_0,\ddot x_0, \dddot x_0)^\top = \boldsymbol{x}_0$. Then the Runge-Kutta 4 method writes
$$
\boldsymbol{x}_{n+1} = \boldsymbol{x}_{n} + \frac{h}{6} \left(\boldsymbol{k}_1 + 2\boldsymbol{k}_2 + 2\boldsymbol{k}_3 + \boldsymbol{k}_4\right),
$$
where
$$
\begin{aligned}
\boldsymbol{k}_1 &= \boldsymbol{f}(\boldsymbol{x}_n, t_n) \, ,\\
\boldsymbol{k}_2 &= \boldsymbol{f}(\boldsymbol{x}_n + \tfrac{h}{2}\boldsymbol{k}_1, t_n + \tfrac{h}{2}) \, ,\\
\boldsymbol{k}_3 &= \boldsymbol{f}(\boldsymbol{x}_n + \tfrac{h}{2}\boldsymbol{k}_2, t_n + \tfrac{h}{2}) \, ,\\
\boldsymbol{k}_4 &= \boldsymbol{f}(\boldsymbol{x}_n + h \boldsymbol{k}_3, t_n + h ) \, .
\end{aligned}
$$