# Difficulty using Excel to solve the double pendulum problem using RK4 to solve four simultaneous first order ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, runge-kutta-methods

I have set up a spreadsheet in Excel to solve the double pendulum problem using RK4 on the four first order DEs. However it isn't working, as the energy in the system is increasing drastically, instead of staying constant. I have spent days (literally) checking the Lagrangian and the spreadsheet entries, and I can't find any faults. I wonder if I am mis-applying the RK4 procedure. I can't find any examples of this in Excel - only Matlab, which is quite different, and I don't have it! I'm desperate and so thought I would post here.

I have four first order DEs. The first two are simple  W'=Y,   X'=Z.    Y' & Z' are both very long with terms in W, X, Y & Z.    So, I have

```
W'=f(t,Y)

X'=f(t,Z)

Y'=f(t,X,Y,Z)

Z'=f(t,X,Y,Z)
```

I calculate

```
Wn+1 = Wn + h/6*(J1 + 2*J2 + 2*J3 + J4)

Xn+1 = Xn + h/6*(K1 + 2*K2 + 2*K3 + K4)

Yn+1 = Yn + h/6*(L1 + 2*L2 + 2*L3 + L4)

Zn+1 = Zn + h/6*(M1 + 2*M2 + 2*M3 + M4)
```

The values of these constants are worked out as follows: (Is this where I'm going wrong?)

```
J1 = f(tn, Yn)

J2 = f(tn + h/2, Yn + h/2*L1) 

J3 = f(tn + h/2, Yn + h/2*L2)

J4 = f(tn + h, Yn + h*L3)
```

The values for K1, K2, K3 & K4 are calculated in the same way using Zn & M1, M2 M3 & M4.

As Y is a function f(t, W, X, Y, Z), I calculate as follows:

```
L1 = f(tn, Wn, Xn, Yn, Zn)

L2 = f(tn + h/2, Wn + h/2*J1, Xn + h/2*K1, Yn + h/2*L1, Zn + h/2*M1)

L3 = f(tn + h/2, Wn + h/2*J2, Xn + h/2*K2, Yn + h/2*L2, Zn + h/2*M2)

L4 = f(tn + h, Wn + h*J3, Xn + h*K3, Yn + h*L3, Zn + h*M3).
```

The values for M1, M2, M3 & M4 used to calculate Z were computed in the exact same manner as for  L1 etc. above.

If anyone can identify a flaw in my methodology and let me know I would be very grateful.

Comment: There is a free variant called Octave that you can get. Can you post the four equations and initial conditions? Recall, that each of these equations is interspersed because there is a dependency from one equation to the next, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/721076/help-with-using-the-runge-kutta-4th-order-method-on-a-system-of-2-first-order-od

Comment: In addition to [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) (which is easiest to use on Linux systems), consider [Scilab](http://www.scilab.org/), which is also free, also mostly Matlab-compatible and is easy to install on Windows or Mac.

Comment: @FionnOCeallaigh: Also, here is a smaller example, but might be useful using the spreadsheet approach: http://epublications.bond.edu.au/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1130&context=ejsie

Comment: Hopefully you use different function names for the different variables, not all `f`. -- Everything else looks good. Try to separate problems by solving a simpler system with known solution to exclude typing errors in the RK4 part. -- Another alternative is to install a python environment, using numpy and matplotlib this kind of problem can be solved in a few handful of lines.

Comment: The equations are θ1' = ω1
θ2' = ω2

Comment: I used the above equations when I had such trouble with the Lagrangian I worked out - even though I checked the Lagrangian against that posted by Wolfram. The weird thing is that when I check the total system energy, the values tend to be consistent regardless of step size. I tried 100, 1000 and 10,000 steps and the error after 1 sec is very consistent, as is the time to record an error of 1% (0.230 seconds in all cases).

Comment: Sorry, I see my earlier comment didn't post as I thought. The equations from http://www.myphysicslab.com/dbl_pendulum.html and I derived them myself also. They are derived directly, rather than via the Lagrangian. I am also referring to a powerpoint presentation online which solves 2 coupled ODEs  https://controls.engin.umich.edu/wiki/images/6/60/Numerical_Solving_in_Excel,_Unnarrated.ppt.  Even though there is a small error in it, (they mistakenly include a 1/2 in the F4 and G4 terms, the rest seems correct. When I repeated their work without the error, I got a minuscule error.

Comment: Additional information about your efforts you should directly edit into the question text, either modifying it (for extra links etc.) or by adding an extra section. Thanks.

Comment: Could you also add a table with the results after 1s as indicated above? And perhaps also the configuration and initial state that you use to be able to reproduce similar results with other means. -- It is rather difficult to answer your (debugging) question without having the code that is used.

Answer (score 3):

The goal is to use a fourth order Runge-Kutta Method to solve two converted $2nd$ order differential equations into four $1st$ order differential equations given by the double pendulum.

Depending on initial conditions, this system can show chaotic behavior, so play around with initial conditions (or seek them out on the web).

The system is given by:

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\theta_1' = \omega_1 \\ 
\theta_2' = \omega_2 \\ 
\omega_1' = \dfrac{-g(2 m_1 + m_2) \sin \theta_1 - m_2 g \sin(\theta_1 - 2 \theta_2) - 2 \sin(\theta_1 - \theta_2)m_2(\omega_2^2 L_2 + \omega_1^2 L_1 \cos(\theta_1 - \theta_2))}{L_1(2 m_1 + m_2 - m_2 \cos(2 \theta_1 - 2 \theta_2))} \\
\omega_2' = \dfrac{2 \sin(\theta_1 -\theta_2)(\omega_1^2 L_1(m_1 + m_2) + g(m_1 + m_2) \cos(\theta_1) + \omega_2^2 L_2 m_2 \cos(\theta_1 - \theta_2))}{L_2(2 m_1 + m_2 - m_2 \cos(2 \theta_1 - 2 \theta_2))}
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

Here is an implementation and it must be done in the order shown because of the dependencies. I changed some of the variable names, so you will have to adapt it, but it is exactly your problem. I used the equations from the web site you linked.

```
g = 9.81
mass1 = 1. 
mass2 = 1.
len1 = 1.
len2 = 1.
f1[t, x, u, y, v] = y
f2[t, x, u, y, v] = v
f3[t, x, u, y, v] = (-g(2 mass1 + mass1)Sin[x]- mass2 g Sin[x-2u]
 -2Sin[x-u]mass2(v^2 len2 + y^2 len1 Cos[x-u]))/(len1(2 mass1
 + mass2 - mass2 Cos[2x-2u]))
f4[t, x, u, y, v] = (2Sin[x-u](y^2 len1(mass1 + mass2)+ 
g (mass1 + mass2)Cos[x]+v^2 len2 mass2 Cos[x-u]))/(len2(2 mass1
+ mass2 - mass2 Cos[2x-2u]))
x = 0.0 Pi
u = -0.25 Pi
y = 0
v = 0
t = 0
h = 0.01
n = 5000
Do from i = 1 to n
  j1 = f1[t, x, u, y, v]
  k1 = f2[t, x, u, y, v]
  l1 = f3[t, x, u, y, v]
  m1 = f4[t, x, u, y, v]
  j2 = f1[t + h/2, x + h/2*j1, u + h/2*k1, y + h/2*l1, v + h/2*m1]
  k2 = f2[t + h/2, x + h/2*j1, u + h/2*k1, y + h/2*l1, v + h/2*m1]
  l2 = f3[t + h/2, x + h/2*j1, u + h/2*k1, y + h/2*l1, v + h/2*m1]
  m2 = f4[t + h/2, x + h/2*j1, u + h/2*k1, y + h/2*l1, v + h/2*m1]
  j3 = f1[t + h/2, x + h/2*j2, u + h/2*k2, y + h/2*l2, v + h/2*m2]
  k3 = f2[t + h/2, x + h/2*j2, u + h/2*k2, y + h/2*l2, v + h/2*m2]
  l3 = f3[t + h/2, x + h/2*j2, u + h/2*k2, y + h/2*l2, v + h/2*m2]
  m3 = f4[t + h/2, x + h/2*j2, u + h/2*k2, y + h/2*l2, v + h/2*m2]
  j4 = f1[t + h, x + h*j3, u + h*k3, y + h*l3, v + h*m3]
  k4 = f2[t + h, x + h*j3, u + h*k3, y + h*l3, v + h*m3]
  l4 = f3[t + h, x + h*j3, u + h*k3, y + h*l3, v + h*m3]
  m4 = f4[t + h, x + h*j3, u + h*k3, y + h*l3, v + h*m3]
  x = x + h*(j1 + 2*j2 + 2*j3 + j4)/6
  u = u + h*(k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4)/6
  y = y + h*(l1 + 2*l2 + 2*l3 + l4)/6
  v = v + h*(m1 + 2*m2 + 2*m3 + m4)/6
  t = t + h
End Do
```

Of course, there are much cleaner approaches in code, but since you are using a spreadsheet, this gives everything in a form like you posted. Here are various plots for each of the parameters with each other for the initial conditions (recall that this system can exhibit chaotic behavior based on the initial conditions).

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @LutzL: Thanks for the comment, done.

Comment: Nice. With the nearly periodic graphs it strongly indicates that a proper implementation will preserve energy and momentum, so there is no numerical/theoretical problem, and the question reduces, with high probability, to a problem with the implementation.

Comment: Many thanks for this. These are the exact equations I am using. I am working through it and hope to get the beautiful graphs you got.

Comment: Many thanks to all who contributed on this. The consensus here was correct. The well laid procedure above was exactly what I was implementing in Excel, but seeing it written out so clearly helped me check against what I was doing in Excel. Variable's beautiful graphs and Lutzl's clear conclusions convinced me to again check my implementation. I found a couple of minor issues (missing brackets and a wrong energy calculation), and  now everything works perfectly. Thank you.