# Solving system of differential equations using Runge Kutta method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, runge-kutta-methods, python

I have two differential equations:

\begin{align}\frac{dx}{dt} &= 1 -(1+b)x+ax^2y\\
\frac{dy}{dt} &= bx - ax^2y\end{align}

I have been asked to solve them on Python using the Runge Kutta (4th order) method. I know how to solve a single ODE using this method, but don't know how to extend it to a system of ODEs.

Any help (or pointers) would be greatly appreciated,

Jack

Comment: Maybe see: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/721076/help-with-using-the-runge-kutta-4th-order-method-on-a-system-of-2-first-order-od

Comment: A typical implementation might look like the example code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34967062/3088138), there are also [fancy tricks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32928543/understanding-python-lambdas) using [lambda expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41470860/using-lambda-functions-in-rk4-algorithm).

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

You can reduce your system using the first equation:
$$
ax^2y = x' - 1+b+bx
$$
and so
$$
y = \frac{x' - 1+b+bx}{ax^2}
$$
(assuming $a \ne 0$) and now your ODE system will become a 2nd order ODE.

Comment: Thanks! Do I just substitute y from above into the bottom ode in my question? And then apply Runge Kutta?

Comment: @Jack yes, don't forget to compute $y'$ first :) Note that if you just add your equations, you get $x' + y' = 1-x$...

Comment: However, this helps you nothing with Runge-Kutta, as most numerical methods are formulated for first order systems. And if you wanted to reduce complexity, you would see that in the sum of both equations $x'+y'=1$ so that $x+y=t+C$.

Comment: Actually, converting nice smooth system of ODEs to a first order ODE with singularities is a bad idea when using numerical methods.

Comment: @Evgeny i agree, but if the only thing OP known how to implement is this, why not let him implement it in an unstable way instead of implementing nothing or spending a week reading up?

Comment: @gt6989b I agree that something here is slightly better than nothing :) but seriously, rewriting Runge-Kutta for systems of ODEs doesn't take a week reading up -- it's a matter of few hours at worst and ten minutes at best. Sometimes your suggestion is useful (see Henon trick which is used for refining Poincare map).