# Can runge kutta method solve this equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, runge-kutta-methods

I'm still a high school student and I'm undergoing a project which involves solving the following differential equations. Is it possible to use runge kutta 4th order method to solve the following. I see that u can use runge kutta method easily if its $\frac{dv_{x}}{dv_{y}} or \frac{dv_{y}}{dv_{x}}$, but in this case it is $\frac{dv_{x}}{dt} and \frac{dv_{y}}{dt}$.
The initial conditions are $ t=0, v_x=0, v_y=0$
\begin{align}
\frac{dv_{x}}{dt} &= -kv_y\sqrt{v_x^2 +v_y^2} -bv_x\sqrt{v_x^2 +v_y^2}\\
\frac{dv_{y}}{dt} &= kv_x\sqrt{v_{x}^2 + v_{y}^2} - bv_y\sqrt{v_x^2 + v_y^2}-mg
\end{align}
to get out a function of $ v_x (t) $ and $ v_y (t)$.
Please tell me if I'm lacking any information as I'm new to this blog.

Comment: Yes, see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/721076/help-with-using-the-runge-kutta-4th-order-method-on-a-system-of-2-first-order-od?rq=1

Comment: Thanks that link was super helpful

Comment: One should in general avoid the component-wise implementation. For 2 components it is okay, but it gets doubly confusing if you want to integrate the position along with the velocity. In a vector based code, you just extend the derivatives function. A nice example in Python code is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27791336/need-help-fixing-my-implementation-of-rk4

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  You have two coupled differential equations.  Runge-Kutta will work fine for this.  Write $\vec v= \begin {pmatrix} v_x \\ v_y \end {pmatrix}$ and you have $\frac d{dt}\vec v =f(\vec v)$ to solve.  When Runge-Kutta asks for a derivative at certain conditions, you can calculate it.

Comment: Thanks alot this is working and is it possible if u type up the OCTAVE code for me. just leave constants for example k and b in this case as k= , b =. I want to check if my result is consistent with the computer

Comment: I know nothing about OCTAVE.  There should be a canned Runge-Kutta package available.

Comment: By the way just curious how do we classify the order and type of my diffential equation. For what i know it's non -linear and how can I tell if its 4th order when there are two simultaneous equations