# System of ODEs Runge-Kutta method.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, runge-kutta-methods

I need to solve the following Cauchy problem using Runge Kutta method (do 2 iterations).
$$ y'(t)=x(t)y(t)+x^2(t)$$
$$ x'(t)=y^2(t)$$
$$ y(0)=x(0)=1 $$
Let $h = 1/2 $, then we get 
$x(1/2) = x(0) + \frac{1}{6}(k_1+2k_2+2k_3+k_4) $
$ k_1 = y^2(0) = 1 $
$ k_2 = y^2(1/4) $ 
What should I do in this case, when $ y^2(1/4) $ is unknown? Find it approximation (for example using Euler method)? Am I missing something?

Comment: You can't apply the RK4 method for a single ODE to system of ODEs. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/721076/help-with-using-the-runge-kutta-4th-order-method-on-a-system-of-2-first-order-od) for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $f(\binom{x}{y})=\binom{y^2}{x^2+xy}$. Give the state vector a different name, $v=\binom{x}{y}$. Then 
$$
k_1=hf(v_0)
$$

The vector $k_2$ is computed at the position $v_0+\frac12k_1$,
$$
k_2=hf(v_0+\tfrac12k_1)=\pmatrix{h(y_0+\tfrac12k_{y1})^2\\h(x_0+\tfrac12k_{x1})^2+h(x_0+\tfrac12k_{x1})(y_0+\tfrac12k_{y1})}
$$
etc.

It is useful to have the evaluation of $f$ as a separate function so that one is forced to compute the intermediate positions only once.